# Object values returns nil after passing data to the Object

Tags: ios, swift, object

I am trying to learn MVVM design pattern and writing clean and readable code. The problem is that i get nil values from the object i map my json response object to. I have checked most of the things i am doing them right however i still get nils. Here is my code.

Search Object :

```
class SearchResultObj: NSObject {

var status : Bool
var name: String?
var publicKey: String?
var profileImage: String?
var accountType: String?

init (model: SearchResultObj) {

    if let value = model.status as? Bool {
        self.status = value
    }else{
        self.status = false
    }
    if let fullname = model.name {
        self.name = fullname
    }else{
        self.name = nil
    }

    if let key = model.publicKey {
        self.publicKey = key
    }else{
        self.publicKey = nil
    }

    if let profimage = model.profileImage {
        self.profileImage = profimage
    }else{
        self.profileImage = nil
    }
    if let account = model.accountType {
        self.accountType = account
    }else{
        self.accountType = nil
    }
  }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
    func searchDataRequested(_ apiUrl: String,_ country: String,_ phone:String) {

        var search: SearchResultObj?

     init() {
          self.search = SearchResultObj()
      }


    let service = ServiceCall(urlServiceCall: apiUrl, country: country, phone: phone)
        let url = URL(string: apiUrl)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let country = country
        let phone = phone


    service.fetchJson(request: request, customerCountry: country, mobileNumber: phone) // making service call and returns json
         { (ok, json) in
            print("CallBack response : \(String(describing: json))")

            self.jsonMappingToSearch(json! as AnyObject)
    }
}

func jsonMappingToSearch(_ json: AnyObject) {

    print( json["fullName"] as! String?) // This returns a value 
    search?.name = json["fullName"] as! String?
    search?.profileImage = json["image"] as! String?
    search?.publicKey = json["publicKey"] as! String?
    search?.accountType = json["accountType"] as! String?
    search?.status = (json["status"] as! Bool?)!
    testResponse()
}

func testResponse(){  

    // testing to see if my object contains anything
    print(search?.name as Any )
    print(search?.profileImage as Any )
    print(search?.publicKey as Any )
    print(search?.accountType as Any )
    print(search?.status as Any )
}
```

So i make the service call in a seperate class and then pass the response in a completion handler to the method self.jsonMappingToSearch(json! as AnyObject). Afterwards i want to map the response to my SearchObject. When i print out values of the json object i do get actual values however after the map function runs, i am unable to get any value in the object as it returns all nils.

Comment: Where is your search variable? Can you show that?

Comment: i have updated it

Comment: where do you see it's nil? I'm wondering if it's not an issue because of asynchronism.

Comment: i run  testResponse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're really looking for clean, readable code you should look at the [Codable Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) in Swift 4.   With that, your code becomes something like the following instead of having a lot of manual JSON mapping and should handle nils in the JSON data):

```
class SearchResultObj: NSObject, Codable {

    var status = false
    var name: String?
    var publicKey: String?
    var profileImage: String?
    var accountType: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status
        case name = "fullName"
        case publicKey
        case profileImage = "image"
        case accountType
    }
}

func searchDataRequested(_ apiUrl: String,_ country: String,_ phone:String) {

    let service = ServiceCall(urlServiceCall: apiUrl, country: country, phone: phone)
    let url = URL(string: apiUrl)
    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    let country = country
    let phone = phone

    service.fetchJson(request: request, customerCountry: country, mobileNumber: phone) // making service call and returns json
    { (ok, json) in
        print("CallBack response : \(String(describing: json))")

        //I'm assuming your JSON is just a Data representation of the JSON string here
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let result = decoder.decode(SearchResultObj.self, from: json)

        //Add breakpoint or print to verify the result here
    }
}
```

If you can post the source JSON, that would also help if you're still having issues.

Comment: so if i access my searchObject in my like searchObject.name

Comment: Not sure if there is a question there but yes, searchObject.name.  In the code above, I used 'result' as the variable name instead of 'searchObject' so it would be 'result.name'.   Note that the above also assumes that you're not already deserializing the JSON string into a Dictionary object.   JSONDecoder can take the raw JSON string (as Data) and parse it into the object for you.

Comment: This is how my method looks like :   func fetchJson(request: URLRequest, customerCountry: String, mobileNumber: String, completion: ((Bool, Dictionary<String, Any>?) -> Void)?){

Comment: i get this error : Cannot convert value of type 'Dictionary<String, Any>?' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: Right, that's what I meant by "Note that the above also assumes that you're not already deserializing the JSON string into a Dictionary object."  Can you use a different method on your ServiceCall object to fetch data?   Is there a fetchData method?

Answer (score 0):

Your `init` is *inside* your `searchDataRequested` function so it won't be called.

As a result, your `search` property is never assigned an instance of `SearchResultObj`; it remains `nil`.

If you are just going to assign an empty `SearchResultObj` in your `init` then you may as well just say

```
var search = SearchResultObj()
```

When you declare the property and then you don't need an `init` and you won't need to keep unwrapping `search`.

I do agree, however, with the other answer that you should use `Codable`

Also, this code does not conform to an MVVM architecture anyway. Your Model class would fetch data from the network. The ViewModel exists merely to map between the data in the model and the data needed by a specific View in your app.

You need to use some form of binding, such as KVO or a delegation pattern between your View Model and your View.

Personally, I am not a fan of MVVM on iOS. The architecture originated in a Microsoft environment where data binding is built in, so MVVM is easier to implement. On iOS you end up adding complexity and possibly even 3rd party frameworks to achieve the binding.

If you are just starting with iOS I would suggest that you stick with MVC at first.

Comment: Thank you this answer is really great